# IIS app pool crashing with exception 0xc0020001 in IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server, windows-server-2016

My app pool keeps crashing. From past 4 weeks it was crashed around 8 times.  I'm not sure where to even begin to troubleshoot the issue.

I have checked the code if there is any exception occurred from the code but didn't found anything. May be I have framework 4.0 and on server it is 4.7 so may be it conflict?

I used Event Viewer to get the following information:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          9/5/2017 1:23:23 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      OnCloud2018
Description:
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899135
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.1532, time stamp: 0x5965adf8
Exception code: 0xc0020001
Fault offset: 0x000da9f2
Faulting process id: 0x33b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d325fb79532785
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: bf88b9dd-419a-4a82-bb0b-3dcf4141cf5c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-09-05T17:23:23.192623600Z" />
    <EventRecordID>637389</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>OnCloud2018</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>10.0.14393.0</Data>
    <Data>57899135</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>10.0.14393.1532</Data>
    <Data>5965adf8</Data>
    <Data>c0020001</Data>
    <Data>000da9f2</Data>
    <Data>33b8</Data>
    <Data>01d325fb79532785</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>bf88b9dd-419a-4a82-bb0b-3dcf4141cf5c</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Did you check for breaking changes in 4.7? This is why I always keep my dev machine on the latest version, because I can always target lower versions for production, and don't have to worry about breaking changes in later versions affecting my code. :)

Comment: Seems related: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/167#issuecomment-352849188